# WCF Message Security with Certification

Tags: wcf, security, digital-certificate

I need to call as web services that is SSL encrypted and where the SOPA message has to be digital signed

I’m new to WCF, and this is what I have so far, but I still can get it right.

E.g. of SOAP message

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mod="http://model.bxd.fi"  xmlns:cor="http://bxd.fi/CorporateFileService">
<soapenv:Header>
   <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis- open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="CertId-9502902" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-pen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message- security-1.0#Base64Binary">
       S..=
    </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    <ds:Signature Id="Signature-22310861" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
           <ds:Reference URI="#id-23633426">
              <ds:Transforms>
                   <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transforms>
              <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
              <ds:DigestValue>yM2…TE=</ds:DigestValue>
           </ds:Reference>
     </ds:SignedInfo>
     <ds:SignatureValue>nc…brQ=</ds:SignatureValue>
     <ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-7..8">
         <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-00401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="STRId-2471808">
             <wsse:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis- 200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#CertId-2902"/>
         </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
   </ds:Signature>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-    utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id426">
   <cor:getUserInfoin>
       <mod:RequestHeader>…..<mod:RequestHeader>
       <mod:ApplicationRequest>ASD..<mod:ApplicationRequest>
   </cor:getUserInfoin>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Client Code

```
var cfs = new ServiceClient();

var data = new XmlDocument();
data.Load("C:\\Temp\\testxml2.xml");

var requestHeader = new RequestHeader
{
    Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
    SenderId = "1",
    RequestId = "2",
    UserAgent = "3",
    ReceiverId = "4",
};

var uploadFileRequest = new UploadFileRequest
{
    ApplicationRequest = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data.OuterXml),
    RequestHeader = requestHeader
};

var userResp = cfs.uploadFile(uploadFileRequest);
```

App.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
     <endpointBehaviors>
       <behavior name="endpointCredentialsBehavior">
         <clientCredentials>
           <clientCertificate findValue="b7 ......... 99"
                           storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                           x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
         </clientCredentials>
       </behavior>
       </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <bindings>
     <wsHttpBinding>
       <binding name="WSHttpBinding" >
         <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" >
         <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
         <message clientCredentialType ="Certificate"/>
         </security>
       </binding>
     </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client>
     <endpoint address="https://..../Service"
            behaviorConfiguration="endpointCredentialsBehavior"
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding"
            contract="FileServices"
            name="WSHttpBindingEndPoint">
     </endpoint>
   </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

I guess that the problem is the bindings (?)

security mode="Transport" = no security element in header.

security mode="Message" = https is invalid, expected http.

security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" = security element in header BUT no message in the body part.

Or do I need to use WSE ?

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**
new Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="endpointCredentialsBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="b7 ... 99"
                               storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                               x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
       </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"  messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
          </security>
          <httpsTransport/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://..Services"
                behaviorConfiguration="endpointCredentialsBehavior"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
                contract="FileServices"
                name="WSHttpBindingEndPoint">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.diagnostics>
   ..
   </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most details you need are in this [WCF security post](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/12-common-wcf-interop-confusions.html).
Use this binding:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="NewBinding0">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
    <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
    </security>
    <httpTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

And add this attribute to the data contract:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ServiceReference1.SimpleServiceSoap",     ProtectionLevel=System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign)]
```

The post also specifies how to easily dismiss some of the errors you may encounter.

Comment: I added your binding and attribute, but it did't help, the header still has no secure element

Comment: publish how your full config looks like. most probably the endpoint is not correctly linked to the binding configuration. try to explicitly add it in the proxy ctor or rebuild the config file

Comment: @YaronNaveh can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696430/unable-to-call-simple-soap-service